# Unable to append external information to my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get information from a url and print it out on my mobile webpage. The details on the url are as follows:

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)#11 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2014-04-23 00:00:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(15) "America/Chicago"
}
{"bank":"-946.30","cash":"-89.46","daily_aim":"-47.08","spent_today":"824.00"}
```

I want to print out on my mobile webpage as follow:

Bank: $-946.30

Cash: $-89.46

Daily Budget: $-47.08

Today's Expense: $824.00

The following is my codes but they are not working. Please advice what I am doing wrong. I looked up the API and following that. Thanks.

Script

```
$.getJSON( "http://testwebsite.com/test.html", function( data ) {
    var wrap = $("<div/>").attr('data-role', 'page');
    $("<p/>",{
        text:"Bank: $"+ data.bank
    }).appendTo(wrap); 
    $("<p/>",{
        text:"Cash: $"+ data.cash
    }).appendTo(wrap); 
    $("<p/>",{
        text:"Daily Budget: $"+ data.daily_aim
    }).appendTo(wrap); 
    $("<p/>",{
        text:"Today's Expense: $"+ data.spent_today
    }).appendTo(wrap); 
    wrap.appendTo('#budgetList'); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="budget" data-theme="e">
            <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Budget</h1>    
        </header>
        <article data-role="content">
            <div id="budgetList">
                <!--fill up with info from url-->
            </div>
        </article>
        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1></h1>
        </footer>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are appending correctly. I think it should be one long string of content appended once - something like:

```
$.getJSON( "http://testwebsite.com/test.html", function( data ) {
    var wrap = '<div data-role="page">' +
               '<p>Bank: ' + data.bank + '</p>' +
               '<p>Cash: ' + data.cash + '</p>' +
               '<p>Daily Budget: ' + data.daily_aim + '</p>' +
               '<p>Todays Expense: ' + data.spent_today + '</p>' +
               '</div>';

    $('#budgetList').html(wrap); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I amended to your codes but it still shows a blank screen.

Comment: Edited code - try setting the inner html instead of appending

Comment: Tried that. Still outputs a blank screen.

Comment: can you breakpoint the function in developer tools and see if the `data` object actually contains the JSON you expect?

Comment: I am not getting anything from the data. This is the actual url: http://kuttykilly.net46.net/test.html

Comment: Ah, I see - that URL does not return JSON, it returns a string formatted as HTML. getJSON expects JSON to be returned. If the URL is amended to be a web service which return just the JSON then my answer will work.